# Multiply view resolvers to different requests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpwebrequest

I have read quite a few posts on ViewResolvers in Spring and I still have a question. I have a DispatcherServlet named dispatcher in my deployment descriptor and it maps "/" all URLs to view resolvers in dispatcher-servlet.xml. I have only one right now.

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And a controller:

```
@Controller
public class ItemsController {

@RequestMapping("/service")
public String service()
{
    System.out.println("From ItemsController...");
    return "service";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home()
{
    System.out.println("From ItemsController...");
    return "index";
}
}
```

So jspViewResolver returns, in case /service is requested, "WEB-INF/jsp/service.jsp". That's fine. But if I want to map requests to html or xhtml files. What need I do? Add another dispatcher? Please, help me out here. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section [15.5.2. Chaining ViewResolvers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining) of the Spring documentation. This allows you to use multiple `InternalResourceViewResolver` instances.

---

You can also add other view resolvers to your `applicationContext`, e.g.,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
<bean id="someView" class="....."/>
```

Then in your annotated controller, when you return the string `"someView"` the bean with the same id will be used as your view instead of your jsp resolver. When names are conflicting you have to use the `order` property to set which resolver gets precedence.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get that to work. What is a resolver called which can resolve to html file? For example, by calling ".../xhtml" from a web browser I want to be redirected on "newhtml.html" page.

Comment: An alternative would be in your `web.xml` to only map `*.jsp` which lets app html/xhtml pages pass through. Using spring 3.0.5 you can also use [mvc:resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources)

Comment: So you're saying there is no other way than to add another dispatcher servlet and map it to html pages?

Comment: No, you can create as many servlet as you like. Map them e.g., by `*.jsp` for the first, `*.html` for the second, and so on.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't realize that's what you meant. Still, if you only map a servlet to `*.jsp` you can still serve html pages (if they're located _outside_ of WEB-INF) without any controller mapping.

Comment: Can you provide some examples how to do that from inside ItemsController?

Comment: Files put in the parent directory of WEB-INF will automatically be accessible without any intermediate controller, assuming you put the mapping `*.jsp` rather than `/*` in your web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

htmlsolver.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<% response.sendRedirect("/rantservice/newhtml.html"); %>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hope/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```